# Proving this log function is continuous

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, continuity

I'm just trying to do a basic $\delta - \epsilon$ proof, but I'm getting lost finding delta.  The function is $f(x) = -\log_2(\frac{1-x}{x})$ so I get that I need $|\log_2 \frac{x-xv}{v-xv}| \lt \epsilon$ so $\frac{x-xv}{v-xv} \lt 2^\epsilon$, but I'm struggling with getting the variables out of the way and manipulating this to have $\delta(v)$

EDIT: $x,v \in (0,1), f: (0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Comment: Note that
$$
f(x)=-\log_2\left(\frac{1-x}x\right) = \frac{\log x - \log(1-x)}{\log 2}
$$
and $x\mapsto\log x$ is continuous, hence $f$ is continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget you really need the absolute value bounded, so you have to consider the lower bound too:

$$
\begin{aligned}
2^{-\epsilon}<\frac{x(1-v)}{v(1-x)}<2^{\epsilon}&\iff 2^{-\epsilon}\frac{1-x}{x}<\frac{1}{v}-1<2^{\epsilon}\frac{1-x}{x}\\[10pt]
&\iff 2^{-\epsilon}\frac{1-x}{x}+1<\frac{1}{v}<2^{\epsilon}\frac{1-x}{x}+1\\[10pt]
&\iff\frac{2^{-\epsilon}-2^{-\epsilon}x+x}{x}<\frac{1}{v}<\frac{2^{\epsilon}-2^{\epsilon}x+x}{x}\\[10pt]
&\iff\frac{x}{2^{\epsilon}-2^{\epsilon}x+x}<v<\frac{x}{2^{-\epsilon}-2^{-\epsilon}x+x}.
\end{aligned}
$$